# Expo 50 app fails to build iOS in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: react-native, azure-devops, expo

I have created a new app using `npx create-expo-app new-app` and all works fine locally. I've added some testing libraries (jest, nightwatch) but basically it's still a vanilla Expo Go app (it's a template for use by the development team).

Now I am building my Azure DevOps pipelines. I have copied a working version of my yaml pipelines from an app I created late last year (let's call it old-app) that works fine for that app.

The issue seems to be that new-app uses Expo SDK 50 and React Native 0.73.4, whereas old-app uses Expo SDK 49 and React Native 0.72.6. This has caused lots of issues in the pipelines which I've fixed, for example I needed to ensure the pipeline uses Android 17. My Android pipeline now works fully.

The issue on iOS has to do with signing the app as part of the XCode@5 build step. Here is my yaml:

```
  - task: Xcode@5
    displayName: "Build IPA"
    inputs:
      actions: "build"
      configuration: "Release"
      sdk: "iphoneos"
      xcWorkspacePath: "ios/newapp.xcworkspace"
      scheme: "NewApp"
      packageApp: true
      exportPath: "output"
      signingOption: "manual"
      signingIdentity: "$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)" # set from previous step
      provisioningProfileUuid: "$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)"    # set from previous step
      useXcpretty: false
```

The issue seems to be that I am attempting to sign the pods, and they do not allow it? I get multiple errors like this:

`/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: error: <module> does not support provisioning profiles. <module> does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile New App has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target '<module>' from project 'Pods')`

and finally

`##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/xcodebuild' failed with exit code 65`

I've experimented with setting `signingOptions` to 'auto' or 'default' but of course I need to sign my app manually with my own certificate.

Any ideas? Or do I just have to downgrade to the versions that work for old-app?

Comment: 1. "all works fine locally" - You can try to set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine and run the pipeline using it. Then check if the pipeline has the same error. 2. Maybe you can try to downgrade to the versions that work for old-app and check what's the result.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I am also experiencing the same issue

Comment: I'm afraid not. It looks like I'm going to have to downgrade to Expo SDK 49 and React Native 0.72.6 and use the pipeline yaml that works for my other app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having seen many solutions mentioned similar to [How to fix ' *pod* does not support provisioning profiles' in azure devops build agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419956/how-to-fix-pod-does-not-support-provisioning-profiles-in-azure-devops-build) I decided to implement the changes mentioned there using an Expo plugin. This works nicely, though I know it's a brittle solution and relies on the structure of the podfile being consistent:

```
const { withDangerousMod } = require("@expo/config-plugins");

const withCustomPodfile = (config) => {
  return withDangerousMod(config, [
    "ios",
    async (config) => {
      const fs = require("fs");
      const podfilePath = `${config.modRequest.platformProjectRoot}/Podfile`;
      let podfileContents = fs.readFileSync(podfilePath, "utf8");

      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419956/how-to-fix-pod-does-not-support-provisioning-profiles-in-azure-devops-build
      const customSettings = `
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
      end
    end`;

      // Match the post_install block
      const postInstallRegex = /post_install do \|installer\|[^]*end/m;
      const match = podfileContents.match(postInstallRegex);

      // NOTE: This is brittle code, and relies on the structure of the existing file to be consistent
      if (match) {
        // Find the last "end" in the matched block
        const ends = [...match[0].matchAll(/end/g)];
        if (ends.length >= 4) {
          // Find the fourth-to-last "end" position
          const fourthLastEndIndex = ends[ends.length - 4].index;
          // Insert custom settings before the second-to-last "end"
          const modifiedBlock =
            match[0].substring(0, fourthLastEndIndex) +
            customSettings +
            "\n  " +
            match[0].substring(fourthLastEndIndex);
          podfileContents = podfileContents.replace(match[0], modifiedBlock);
        }
      } else {
        // Append a new post_install block if it doesn't exist
        podfileContents += `
post_install do |installer|${customSettings}
end
`;
      }

      // Write the modified Podfile contents back to the file
      fs.writeFileSync(podfilePath, podfileContents, "utf8");

      // Optional: Log the modified Podfile contents for verification
      // console.log("Modified Podfile contents:");
      // console.log(podfileContents);

      return config;
    },
  ]);
};

module.exports = withCustomPodfile;
```